# different answers using pow() in c++ when used in different places, although same is expected

Tags: c++, pow

I have shown two pieces of code. I don't quite understand how using pow() differently brings about a difference in these codes. Thanks a lot in advance.

In this problem you are to calculate the sum of all integers from 1 to n,but you should take all powers of two with minus in the sum.For example, for n = 4 the sum is equal to  - 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 =  - 4, because 1, 2 and 4 are 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup> and 2<sup>2</sup> respectively. Calculate the answer for t values of n.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>    
typedef long long ll;
typedef double dl;
using namespace std;
int main() {
   ll n,t;

   ll i,cnt=0;
   cin>>t;
   while(t--)// for 't' number of test cases 
  {
       cin>>n;

           for(i=1,cnt=0;i<=n;i*=2,cnt++); //counting number of terms in the GP:1,2,4,....
           cout<<setprecision(20)<<((n*(n+1))/2)-(2*(pow(2,cnt)-1))<<endl;
  }
  return 0;

}
//output for above code:499999998352516352
// and the slightly modified code..


#include<bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long ll;
typedef double dl;
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ll n,t;

    ll i,cnt=0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)// for 't' number of test cases
    {
    cin>>n;

    for(i=1,cnt=0;i<=n;i*=2,cnt++); 
    ll k=(pow(2,cnt)); //instead of directly printing the answer, 'k' is computed and then used to find the answer.
    cout<<setprecision(20)<<((n*(n+1))/2)-(2*(k-1))<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
//output for above code:499999998352516354
// the second one is the correct answer, the first one is wrong. how does pow() change the values here?
```

Comment: `pow()` operates on (and returns) a floating-point number. Floating-point numbers are inherently inexact.

Comment: Thanks, but then how do we know which usage would work properly?

Comment: Define "properly." Floating-point numbers are, in their very essence, inexact. You can only ask whether the coputation error is within an acceptable tolerance for you. Have a look at [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for details.

Comment: `k` is of type `long long` and `pow` returns a `double.` Your inconsistency arises from the conversion between types being performed in your second example. In the first example it should just keeping using floating-point arithmetic, which (as has already been pointed out) is inexact. In the second example it's all integer arithmetic after the initial call to `pow`.

Comment: @Sreenidhi for one, don't use floating-point functions for integer-related problems.

Comment: Are your `for` loops *supposed* to have semicolons after them?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @angew thank you for the link!

Comment: it looks like after the loop `i` is `2**cnt`. Use `i` in place of `pow(2, cnt)`

Comment: The combination of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` is one of the most expletive deleted stupid things that you can do to yourself. This effectively pulls the entire standard library into the global namespace, setting you up for naming collision nightmare.

Comment: I would not trust `pow` to give an exact enough answer to truncate correctly to `ll`, so I wouldn't use it without some adjustment to round accurately.  Since you don't really need it, I wouldn't use it at all.  That said, the actual problem is the one identified by ApproachingDarknessFish.  It is not a matter of the value `pow` returns, it is a matter of all the other computations switched from `ll` to the **type** `pow` returns, because of "promotion" rules.

Comment: Also, `pow` is slightly different from `std::pow`. The template wrapping around `std::pow` converts input datatypes to a convenient floating point type before calling `pow`. Under mingw this can slightly skew the results, but I have no idea why. Things turn out fine if I just use `pow` and do the casting myself.

Comment: On a more useful front, consider not using `pow` at all. There aren't that many exponents of 2 by that will fit in a 64 bit int. Make a static array, or take a closer look at the value of `i` generated by that for loop.

Comment: @user4581301: That's very complex and inefficient, considering you can do plain bit-shifting.

Comment: What are the inputs that you are passing?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If I'm getting you right, you ventured into X-Y space to solve OP's real problem. Yeah, one add, one bit-shift, one compare, and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the value of that is giving you trouble is `n=1000000000`, or 10<sup>9</sup>. The largest integral power of 2 less than or equal to this value is 2<sup>29</sup>. The sum you are trying to calculate is thus (10^9*(10^9+1))/2-2*(2^30-1), or 500000000500000000-2147483646, or 499999998352516354.

Your second approach works because powers of two are exact and because you are using integer arithmetic in your subtraction. Your first approach fails because the expression is calculated as a double. The first term, `n*(n+1)/2`, or 500000000500000000, is "exact", which means there is no error in the floating point representation. The second term, 2147483646, is also exact. The problem in this case occurs with the subtraction. The difference between the two is inexact, which means you've lost precision.

There was no reason for you to use `pow`. You have already computed `pow(2,cnt)`. In fact, you don't need `cnt` at all. Simply use

```
ll k;
for(k=1; k<=n; k*=2);
```